# RXjs groupBy - Group AngularFire Firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to group a `AngularFire` Firestore Collection (Observable[]) by a field, say `userId`.

I have a collection of items, each with varying userId values, and I need to group them into a multidimensional array.  So, convert..

```
[ 
  {userID:1, color:'blue' }, 
  {userId:2, color:'green'}, 
  {userId:1, color:'orange'}
]
```

into

```
[ 
  [
   {userID:1, color:'blue' }, 
   {userId:1, color:'orange'}
  ],
  [
   {userId:2, color:'green'}
  ]
]
```

I'm totally new to RxJs, I get how the `groupBy` operator works when making an `Observable.of(itemsArray)`, but I can't see how to get this to work with the `Observable` returned from `AgularFire`

```
let items:Observable[] = this.afs.collection<Item>('items')
  .snapshotChanges()
  .groupBy( item => item.userId ); //item is actually the array
```

It looks like `AngularFire` returns an `Observable` that emits the Array as a whole, not each element.

If I `map` it, dont I then just have each item in the array, and cant use the `groupBy`?

Any pointers on how to return a `Observable` array of grouped arrays as per above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply turn your observable of array into an observable of the values of the array with:

```
myObservable.flatMap(arr => Rx.Observable.from(arr));
```