# AngularFire2 group data into array of objects Firestore collection

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a collection called `addons`. The collection contains fields namely, `name`, `desc`, `price` and `type`.

I am straight away fetching the data with `this.afs.collection<AddOns>('addons');` which returns `AngularFirestoreCollection<AddOns>`. I have below class file defined for `data` from Firestore Collection.

**AddOns.ts**

```
export class AddOns{
    name?: string;
    desc?: string;
    price?: number;
    type?: string;
}

export class AddOnId extends AddOns{
    aid?: string;
}
```

Since I need metadata too from that collection I have created `AddOnId` class which extends `AddOns` class. To get all the data I do it as below:

```
addOnsList: Observable<AddOnId[]>;

this.addOnsList = this.afs.collection<AddOns>('addons').snapshotChanges().map( x => {
  return x.map(data => {
    const addon = data.payload.doc.data() as AddOns;
    const aid = data.payload.doc.id;
    return {aid, ... addon}
  });
})
```

**[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190224/rxjs-groupby-group-angularfire-firestore-collection?rq=1)** has mentioned the problem of unable to use `groupby` since data that will be returned is `Observable of Array` and also has an answer how to convert `Observable of array` to `Observable of values` using `flatMap`.

I then tried

```
const grouped = this.afs.collection<AddOns>('addons').snapshotChanges()
                    .flatMap( arr => Observable.from(arr))
                    .groupBy(d => d.payload.doc.data().type);
```

But even that does not return desired result. How else can I achieve this? How should I be grouping the data based on their type and turn it into an Observable of values?

Answer (score 0):

Do the grouping inside the Observable map, e.g, `return x.map { ... }.groupBy { ... }` Since you intend to transform the data, not the Observable itself. lodash has a good implementation of groupBy for an array.